# make error 127 /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/g++: not found using Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, make, g++

I am trying to make a program (hisat2) from the source code through Ubuntu. When I do, I get an error 127 and it says the following:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/g++: not found
Makefile:273: recipe for target 'hisat2-build-s' failed
make: *** [hisat2-build-s] Error 127
```

The folder with g++.exe is already added to path. I am a newbie so I was wondering if someone can guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Ubuntu [hisat2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hisat2&searchon=names) package.